# Android - how to capture selected video by intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I'm writting a code that the user can upload video from his phone.

My only problem is that i dont know how to get/save the file.

With the intent the user access to his libary and choose his video.
But then i dont know how to get what he choose

**Here is my code**

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    btnVideo.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAudio.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.btnUploadVideo:
            if(!checkStoragePermission())return;
            uploadVideo();
            break;
        case R.id.btnUploadAudio:
            break;
    }

}

private void uploadVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"),OPEN_MEDIA_PICKER);
}

private boolean checkStoragePermission(){
    int resultCode = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    boolean granted = resultCode == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    if (!granted){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                getActivity(),
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST /*Constant Field int*/
        );
    }
    return granted;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        uploadVideo();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        }
    }
}
```

What should i do on the "onActivityResult"? How should i save/get the user choose.

Comment: `a code that the user can upload video from his phone.`. To where exactly?

Comment: `Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();`. That is the uri for the selected video! So what is your problem?

Comment: `uploadVideo()`. Not a good function name as nothing will be uploaded. The user only picks a video.

Comment: What im trying to do is to save the selected video from the user gallery to the databse. In this case it will be save in firebase. i just want to make sure that      Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();    - is the selected video of the user, or its just the Uri to the video?

Comment: You get an uri as you can see. So what is it that you are asking? You can answer that yourself! It is like if you hat got a file path than you had the path. Not the file itself. There is not much difference in handling a file path or this uri.

Comment: My goal is to get the video and put it on VideoView. The "selectedImageUri" is enough to set in a videoView?

Comment: You were talking about a database?

Comment: Yea, save it in database(Firebase in my case) and also set it on VideoView

Comment: One statement should be enough to start that video in the videoview if the view supports loading videos from uri or content scheme. So what did you try? Like videoView.loadFromUri() or so.

Comment: Well actually, i just want to make sure that its enough that line of code  ** Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();**  to get the video, and then i can do what ever i want to. Like save it on the firebase(database) or use it for the VideoView. - selectedImageUri - in other words is the video?

Comment: `So what did you try? Like videoView.loadFromUri() or so. `

Comment: exacly what i try to do and it didnt go well

Comment: Post your code. And 'it didnt go well' is a description that tells us nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> My only problem is that i dont know how to get/save the file.

Your code has nothing to do with a file.

If you want the use to pick a *file*, use [a third-party file-chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).

Your code is having the user choose a piece of *content*, and that content does not have to be a file, let alone a file that you have direct filesystem access to.

You are welcome to use `data.getData()` to get the `Uri` to the content, then use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on that content, if that meets your needs.